# Redis: share data in heroku with more than one dynos

Tags: heroku, redis

I'm new using heroku and I will pick 4 instances of 2X dynos and I worry about AFAIK there is no share data between dynos.

So my question is, is there a way to save data in all redis(https://addons.heroku.com/rediscloud#250) instances(located on each dynos)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your confusion stems from assuming that Redis runs locally on each dyno. When you use an add-on such as Redis Cloud, Redis is external to all dynos and is run on sperate servers that are operated by the service provider (Redis Labs in this case).

Comment: thanks so much! Now I understand I have to focus my attention on what kind of Redis Cloud plan I have to pick.

Comment: Indeed. The plans are based on the size of your data, so just pick the one that fits your needs. Don't fret too much however, you can always change the plan to increase (or decrease) the amount of RAM that you pay for and the best thing with Redis Cloud is that this **does not** involve any downtime, data loss or configuration changes to the app :)

Comment: well now I'm sure I will pick four 2X dynos, because my request are just sending json objects with a length of 100 max. And there will be a max of 800 concurrents requests.

Answer (score 1):

As long as all your dynos belong to the same app (which appears to be the case), all of them will share the same add-ons, Redis Cloud included. While your app will run distributed across these dynos, all of its connections will be opened to the same Redis database (defined by the `REDISCLOUD_URL' env var) and will therefore be able to share the data in it.

Comment: Thanks again @ItamarHaber , as far as I know every dynos instance has his own RAM and redis works in RAM(each ram of each instance). This is the part that I don't undertand, how redis can be shared. My fear is if one instance falls I will loose sensitive data then I'm looking how reload all data in these instance.